# Unit tests with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, macos, unit-testing, nsurlsession, nsurlcache

I'd like to write unit tests for methods that use the shared `NSURLSession`, and in particular, `NSURLSessionDataTask` to download data. Basically, I would like the target methods to receive mock responses/data without requiring an internet connection.

What is the less unobtrusive way of mocking these components? I was thinking of populating `NSURLCache` with mock responses and data but I feel this assumes too much of how `NSURLSession` and `NSURLSessionDataTask` work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used [`OHHTTPStubs`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs) to mock responses lately.

You just register the stub before you test (example from the README):

```
[OHHTTPStubs stubRequestsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSURLRequest *request) {
    return [request.URL.host isEqualToString:@"mywebservice.com"];
} withStubResponse:^OHHTTPStubsResponse*(NSURLRequest *request) {
    // Stub it with our "wsresponse.json" stub file
    return [OHHTTPStubsResponse responseWithFileAtPath:OHPathForFileInBundle(@"wsresponse.json",nil)
        statusCode:200 headers:@{@"Content-Type":@"text/json"}];
}];
```

Internally, it uses `NSURLProtocol` to intercept the requests and stub them.