# getting output from URLSession in XCUITest

Tags: swift, xcode, urlsession, xcuitest

I'm trying to grab a value from a URL inside a XCUI Test. However it's not outputting so I'm not sure if there's anything I'm supposed to be doing aside from I've already tried in the code below:

```
import XCTest

class ExampleUITests: XCTestCase {


func testExample() {
    print("We are in XCUITest textExample right now")

    let urlString = "https://api.ipify.org/"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }

        guard let data = data
            else {
                print("error found in data")
                return
        }

        print("*******")
        let outputStr  = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!
        print (outputStr)

        }.resume()

}

}
```

Comment: I tried adding in a completion block as mentioned in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810108/swift-http-request-use-urlsession but it still didn't give me any output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, response from server is returned after test is finished. You should add waiting for network response in the test.

At the start of the test add:

`let expectation = expectationWithDescription("")`

At the end of the test add:

```
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5.0) { (error) in
    if error != nil {
        XCTFail(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

And in the network completion block add:

`expectation.fulfill()`

You can get more info about waining for async task in the test for example here [How can I get XCTest to wait for async calls in setUp before tests are run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504712/how-can-i-get-xctest-to-wait-for-async-calls-in-setup-before-tests-are-run).